# Nginx permissions issue: www-data user can't open error log despite 766 permissions

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server where nginx was originally installed by the root user. I now want to run nginx as a non-root user, a new user that I added to both the `sudo` the `www-data` groups. For now, I have yet to install an app server.

When I try to run nginx from this new user, I get the following message:

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()
>   "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied) 2016/08/09
>   22:07:52 [warn] 17609#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the
>   master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 2016/08/09 22:07:52 [emerg] 17609#0: open()
>   "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)

I'm confused why this is an issue — I changed the owner and group of `/var/log/nginx/` to `www-data`. The nginx master process user is root, which I believe is correct, and the sub-processes are running (or trying to run) as `www-data`. The file permissions for `error.log` and `access.log` are 766. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the `user` in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` out of curiosities sake?

Comment: Why do you want to start nginx from non-root user?

Comment: @Darren — the `user` is `www-data`

Comment: @VBart—I'm following instructions from Digital Ocean's docs. They recommend disabling SSH login as root

Comment: How is SSH related to nginx?

Comment: @VBart I'd have to ssh into the server and start nginx at some point, as a non-root user. The server will require maintenance, configuration tweaks, etc., and I'd like to be able to do those from a non-root user

Comment: You can do it with `sudo`. The http-server has to be started as `root` as it needs various privileges, including listening on low port number and opening log files.

Comment: @VBart Yep, that did the trick. Thanks very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably started

```
nginx -t
```

as a normal user. Then you get exactly that misleading error message

if you do it as root or with `sudo` the error should be gone